# Typescript Add types to libraries method arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typeorm

I am using an external library `pg-mem` which exposes `LibAdapters` and it has a method `createTypeormConnection` which accepts few arguments but of type `any`.

```
export interface LibAdapters {
  createTypeormConnection(typeOrmConnection: any, queryLatency?: number): any;
}
```

I want to specify the exact type of these arguments as I am getting a lot of lint errors:

`` Unsafe return of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return ``

How can I specify the types of the arguments & return type of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend exisiting types by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```js
declare module "pg-mem" {
    interface LibAdapters {
        createTypeormConnection(typeOrmConnection: SomeType, queryLatency?: number): SomeOtherType
    }
}
```

Note, that this will add overload of `createTypeormConnection` instead of overriding it, so if you call `createTypeormConnection` with value of type other than `SomeType`, you will still get `any`.